# PlaySound() In C++ Doesn't Work

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to figure this out, and I just can't seem to.

When you include window.h at the top, there is supposed to be a PlaySound() function inside of it.

I added window.h but I keep on getting a "PlaySound was not declared in this scope" error.

I tried going into the project's build options and adding "-lwinmm" into the linker settings, but it *still* doesn't work.

I'm using Code::Blocks.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include` both `windows.h` and `mmsystem.h`, in that order. This is noted in the community section of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I had to add the mmsystem.h as well.

Comment: @user1432532 : According to the documentation, you don't, so the fact that in reality you do is either a Windows SDK bug or a documentation bug -- I'm not sure which.

Comment: Sometimes that documentation makes me want to scream. I usually use `mciSendString` for sound and stuff so...

Comment: Woah, mciSendString is so much better for playing sounds. I can mix sounds easily. Thanks, chris!

Comment: @downvoter : As per SO etiquette, if you're going to downvote an answer (which should only be if it's ["*egregiously sloppy, \[a\] no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)), leave an explanation as to _why_ you're downvoting so that the answer can be improved if necessary.

Comment: @Abrar : Absolutely no idea, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are coding on windows and you actually wanted the interface file called "Windows.h".  Also make sure you are using the correct namespace, I'm not a windows programmer, but that's a start.  I also don't know haw you are loading the file or wether you are using the win32 or .net frameworks.  But then from the sounds of it you might not either.

If you're trying to use .net you can start here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer

win 32 start here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx

ah here it is winCE audio API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx

Comment: `windows.h` is a header file -- not sure what you mean by "interface file". It also exposes a C API, not a C++ one, so there are no namespaces.

Comment: An interface file referes to any file that provides an manner in which to call methods from a linked library.

Comment: Can't say I've heard that before, and it's doubly confusing on Windows where use of [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) is prominent. Thanks for clarifying though. :-]